# Save csv file with numeric parameters value

Tags: python

I have some paramters

```
p=221
q=4.22
r=3.3
```

I want to save my output  values in file named as p_221__q_4.22__r_3.3.csv
i tried this

```
file_name = open('p_{}__q_{}__r_{}.csv'.format(p,q,r),'w')
output.to_csv(filename+'.csv', index=False)
```

but error came as "Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple"

Comment: what format is your output variable? Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes output is a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `output` variable is a pandas dataframe, just use the `to_csv()` function:

```
p=221
q=4.22
r=3.3
output = pd.DataFrame([p,q,r])

file_name = 'p_{}__q_{}__r_{}.csv'.format(p,q,r)
output.to_csv(file_name)
```

Using the to_csv() function precludes the need to open any file using open()